# Get a field's value associated with a function's selected row/field

Tags: postgresql

I have the next `events` table

| event_id | course_id | start | end | creator_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 8 | 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 13 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 5 | 14 |
| 4 | 2 | 5 | 7 | 15 |
| 5 | 2 | 9 | 9 | 16 |
| 6 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 17 |
| 7 | 3 | 7 | 4 | 18 |
| 8 | 3 | 3 | 6 | 19 |
| 9 | 3 | 6 | 8 | 20 |

And when i run this query:

```
SELECT course_id,
            COUNT(*) AS event_count,
            MIN(start) as earliest,
            MAX(end) as latest
        FROM event
        GROUP BY course_id
```

I get the next result:

| course_id | event_count | earliest | latest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 9 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 8 |

So, it groups by course_id and for each course_id it gives me the min(start) as `earliest` and max(end) as `latest` value between events that share the same course_id.

Now what i need is: to also get the creator_id associated with those min(start) and max(end) rows, so for example:
If for:

- `course_id = 1`, earliest is `1`, i also need the `creator_id` associated with that row, which would be 13, and so on,
- for `course_id = 2`, earliest is `2`, i also need the `creator_id` associated with that row, which would be 17
- for `course_id = 3`, earliest is `3`, i also need the `creator_id` associated with that row, which would be 19

So the query result i'm looking for is:

| course_id | event_count | earliest | latest | earliest_creator_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 5 | 13 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 9 | 17 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 8 | 19 |

Is there a way to add that to the query as a column with an alias in any way?
I hope that the explanation is understandable, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a better way than subqueries using `DISTINCT ON`:

```
WITH counted_events AS (
   SELECT event_id,
          course_id,
          count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY course_id) AS event_count,
          start,
          end,
          creator_id
   FROM event
), earl AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (course_id)
          course_id,
          event_count,
          start AS earliest,
          creator_id AS earliest_creator_id
   FROM counted_events
   ORDER BY course_id, start
), late AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (course_id)
          course_id,
          event_count,
          end AS latest,
          creator_id AS latest_creator_id
   FROM counted_events
   ORDER BY course_id, end DESC
)
SELECT course_id,
       event_count,
       earliest,
       latest,
       earliest_creator_id,
       latest_creator_id
FROM earl
   JOIN late USING (course_id, event_count);
```

Comment: This made the trick for me, thank you so much! I don't know about how performant it is but it's definitely somewhere to start from

Answer (score 0):

If your datatypes are all `integer` values as in your example, then you can construct an `integer array` to hold multiple values:

```
with extremes as (
  select course_id, 
         count(*) as event_count,
         min(array[start, creator_id]) as earliest, 
         max(array["end", creator_id]) as latest
    from events
   group by course_id
)
select course_id, event_count, 
       earliest[1] as earliest,
       latest[1] as latest,
       earliest[2] as earliest_creator_id,
       latest[2] as latest_creator_id
  from extremes
 order by course_id;
```

If the types for the times are different, then you can use window functions.

```
select distinct course_id,
       count(*) over we as event_count,
       first_value(start) over we as earliest,
       last_value("end") over wl as latest,
       first_value(creator_id) over we as earliest_creator_id,
       last_value(creator_id) over wl as latest_creator_id
  from events
window we as (partition by course_id order by start 
                rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following),
       wl as (partition by course_id order by "end"
                rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
 order by course_id;
```

[Working fiddle here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=df8507047d897c12ced6953b22bd8341)